# thumbnail video from url using image?

Tags: java, android, thumbnails, video-capture

I already success display thumbnail video from URL on my android app when internet connection is connected, but when internet connection is off the thumbnail doesn't display.

here is my code.

```
Bitmap bmThumbnail;

bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("http://somedomain.com/video/myvideo.mp4", Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND );
imgPhoto.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

i want the thumbnail still display although connection is off,there is away to achieve like save the cache on `sdcard` first, like image cache does? or any other solution to show thumbnail video when internet connection is off?
thanks,

Comment: could you please share the code for generating video thumbnail with URL

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getBitmapFromURL(final Activity activity, String link,
            String filename) throws FileNotFoundException,
            MalformedURLException, IOException {

        /*--- this method downloads an Image from the given URL, 
         *  then decodes and returns a Bitmap object
         ---*/

        File file = null;


        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath()
                + CommonVariable.KCS_IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME_PHONE_MEMORY);

        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        // create a File object for the output file
        File outputFile = new File(file, filename);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

        out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);

        int b;
        while ((b = input.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(b);
        }
        out.close();
        connection.disconnect();

        return outputFile.getAbsolutePath();

    }
```

use this function,it will return string of sdcard path.and use this path u can set bitmap image using below function:

```
    public static void setImagesNew(ImageView img, String pathName,
                Activity activity) {


                  Bitmap  bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(pathName, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND );
img.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);


            bmp = null;
            System.gc();
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

        }
```

i hope this is useful to you...............

Comment: the code always download file first,isn't my need,i want to make thumbnail of video,like capture video in first frame to become jpg file and store to my sdcard,